# Program to recognize multiple modes

Tags: java

I have this code that find the mode of an array. Ex: [1,2,3,3,4] the program will out put 3.0. However, in the case of [1,2,2,3,3,4] the program will output 2.0 because it comes first. I want the program to know that the values 2 and 3 show up twice and thus should return the value Double.NaN(which is what our professor wants). Any help is appreciated, thank you!

P.S. We cannot use any import classes such as java.util.Arrays, etc.
The input array is always sorted.

```
public double mode() {

    double maxValue = 0;

    int maxCount = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {

        int count = 0;

        for (int j = 0; j < data.length; ++j) {

            if (data[j] == data[i])

                ++count;

        } // End of for loop

        if (count > maxCount) {

            maxCount = count;

            maxValue = data[i];

        } // End of if condition

    } // End of for loop
    
    return maxValue;

} // End of method
```

Comment: What do you mean by "finding the mode"?

Comment: The number in the array that occurs the most for example [1,2,2,3,4,5], the value 2 occurs twice so that is the mode, but in [1,2,2,3,3,4], the values 2 and 3 occur twice so both are the mode

Comment: @Progman [Definition of Mode](https://www.mathsisfun.com/definitions/mode.html): The number which appears most often in a set of numbers.

Comment: What problem are you having, detecting a second run with the same length, returning NaN, or something else?

Answer (score 1):

The code in the question finds the same mode value multiple times. E.g. if `data = {1,2,3,3,4}`, when `i = 2` it will find `count = 2` for value `3`, and when `i = 3` it will again find `count = 2` for value `3`.

To recognize multiple *distinct* modes, the code needs to not find the same `mode` value more than once. This is easily achieved by changing the `j` loop to start at `i`, so that subsequent counting of a particular value ends up counting less.

Now that the code will never see the same mode more than once, we can detect multimodal data by checking for `count == maxCount`. If that happens, change `maxValue`, aka the mode, to `NaN`.

We also need to initialize `maxValue` to `NaN` instead of `0`, so the result is `NaN` if `data` is an empty array.

*Note:* This is not the most efficient implementation for finding mode, but it is the least amount of change to fix the code in the question.

```java
public static double mode(double... data) {
    double maxValue = Double.NaN;
    int maxCount = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
        int count = 0;
        for (int j = i; j < data.length; ++j) {
            if (data[j] == data[i])
                ++count;
        }
        if (count == maxCount) {
            maxValue = Double.NaN;
        } else if (count > maxCount) {
            maxCount = count;
            maxValue = data[i];
        }
    }
    return maxValue;
}
```

*Test*

```java
System.out.println(mode(1,2,3,3,4));
System.out.println(mode(1,2,2,3,3,4));
System.out.println(mode(1));
System.out.println(mode());
```

*Output*

```
3.0
NaN
1.0
NaN
```